# HtmlUnit: avoid the «Bad input type: "search", creating a text input» info text

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit

I'm creating a monitor with Selenium Webdriver (in Java) which browses a webpage every few minutes to check if something went wrong when users updated it, so I can send an alarm and revert the page to the last stable status.

Since it's being called by Jenkins in our integration server, I use HtmlUnit instead of a browser with GUI. The routine checks a number of properties, and then logs the correct ones using the standard output, and the erroneous ones to the standard error.

My problem is that the page is using an `<input type="search">`, that isn't recognized by HtmlUnit, so it adds these lines to the error output every time it fetchs the page:

```
abr 30, 2013 1:33:42 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.InputElementFactory createElementNS
INFO: Bad input type: "search", creating a text input
```

Is there a way to get rid of this info text? It's not only logging information that I don't want, but it's also using the incorrect channel, so it's recognized as an error when it really isn't.

Comment: Summarizing, I want to get rid of a specific warning output in Java. Or I want HtmlUnit not to write this message.

Comment: List the version of Selenium and HTMLUnit that you're using.

Comment: Thank you Nathaniel. I'm using version 2.32.0 of selenium-java with HtmlUnitDriver. In case it's relevant, I'm also using version 4.10 of Junit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [configure HtmlUnit's logging level](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/logging.html), so it wouldn't log anything at INFO level or below. That would do it - or do you need other INFO messages?